# Delete history for all browsers with Batch file

Tags: batch-file, browser-history

I am trying to delete the history of IE, FireFox, Chrome and Opera using a batch file when staff log in.  Below is what I have and it works but it also clears the bookmarks and preferences of Chrome and I think Firefox.  How do I just clear the history without clearing bookmarks and preferences.  Any help would be great, thank you.

```
@echo off

rem IE
taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe
start "" "C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe" InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess  255

:: Parse the Local AppData sub path
call :Expand xAppData "%%LocalAppData:%UserProfile%=%%"

set "xFirefox=\mozilla\firefox\profiles"
set "xChrome=\google\chrome\user data"
set "xOpera1=\Local\Opera\Opera"
set "xOpera2=\Roaming\Opera\Opera"

:: Start at the User directory
pushd "%UserProfile%\.."

taskkill /F /IM firefox.exe
taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe
taskkill /F /IM opera.exe

:: Loop through the Users
    for /D %%D in (*) do if exist "%%~fD%xAppData%" (
    rem Check for Firefox
    if exist "%%~fD%xAppData%%xFirefox%" (
        rd /s /q "%%~fD%xAppData%%xFirefox%"
    )

   rem Check for Chrome
   if exist "%%~fD%xAppData%%xChrome%" (
        rd /s /q "%%~fD%xAppData%%xChrome%"
    )

    rem Check for Opera
    if exist "%%~fD%xAppData%%xOpera1%" (
        rd /s /q "%%~fD%xAppData%%xOpera1%"
    )
    if exist "%%~fD%xAppData%%xOpera2%" (
        rd /s /q "%%~fD%xAppData%%xOpera2%"
    )
)
popd
goto End


::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:Expand <Variable> <Value>
if not "%~1"=="" set "%~1=%~2"
goto :eof


:End
endlocal
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just replace the browser data folder with a blank one that still has the bookmarks?

Like...

```
    rem Check for Firefox
    if exist "%%~fD%xAppData%%xFirefox%" (
        rd /s /q "%%~fD%xAppData%%xFirefox%"
        robocopy /e "C:\somewhere\BlankFirefox" "%%~fD%xAppData%%xFirefox%"
    )

   rem Check for Chrome
   if exist "%%~fD%xAppData%%xChrome%" (
        rd /s /q "%%~fD%xAppData%%xChrome%"
        robocopy /e "C:\somewhere\BlankChrome" "%%~fD%xAppData%%xChrome%"
    )

    rem Check for Opera
    if exist "%%~fD%xAppData%%xOpera1%" (
        rd /s /q "%%~fD%xAppData%%xOpera1%"
        robocopy /e "C:\somewhere\BlankOpera1" "%%~fD%xAppData%%xOpera1%"
    )
    if exist "%%~fD%xAppData%%xOpera2%" (
        rd /s /q "%%~fD%xAppData%%xOpera2%"
        robocopy /e "C:\somewhere\BlankOpera2" "%%~fD%xAppData%%xOpera2%"
    )
```

That way it just reverts it back to when they first logged on?